# Access Count of a Blob in Azure Storage v2

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

```
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container.Name -Context $storageContext
# Iterate over the blobs and retrieve additional details
foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
      $LastAccessedOn =$blob.BlobProperties.LastAccessed.ToString()
}
```

I am able to see a property which tells when this blob was last acccessed. Any property which can tell me how many times this blob has been accessed. Outgest/ Reading a blob is a cost factor as well. I am trying optimize my storage

Answer (score 0):

There is no property that you can read to get this information.

What you can do is to use Monitoring for Azure Blob Storage to collect information on when the blob was accessed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage?tabs=azure-portal